# memory allocation for array in c

Tags: c, static-memory-allocation

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int a=17;
  scanf("%d",&a);

  int arr[a];

  printf("%lu", sizeof(arr));
}
```

Memory for array "arr" should be allocated at compile time but in this case it takes the value of "a" from the user(run-time) and allocates the same size for the array. Please Clarify.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is known as a variable-length array. It's been standard in C since C99.

So no, the memory should not be allocated at compile time for code like this. That would be impossible, of course.

Also, values of type `size_t` (like those generated by the `sizeof` operator) should be printed using `%zu`.